# Join BQ tables using a comparator

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I'm stuck on this query! I have a table `Logs.Customer_Internet_Activity_Information` which contains test data for customers. There is a IP address in the table. In the other table
`Logs.IP` there is a `startIpnum` and a `endIpNum` and a `localID`. The `startIPnum` is the lower IP address in the range and the `endIpNum` is the max IP address in the range. Each range has an Local ID that references a city , country, etc...

My query is trying to look up the customers IP in the Range to find what is the local ID.

```
Select t1.email ,t1.IP , t2.Local_ID

from [TablewithcustomerIP address] as t1 cross join [table with IP ranges] as t2

where t1.IP between t2.startIpNum and t2.endIpNum
```

Comment: Could you please comment on what your query currently does, and how that differs from your desired behavior?

Comment: I get this error even when I switch the tables...   3.96 - 3.168: The JOIN operator's right-side table must be a small table. Switch the tables if the left-side table is smaller, or use JOIN EACH if both tables are larger than the maximum described at http://goo.gl/wXqgHs.

Comment: did you try to change your "JOIN" to a "JOIN EACH" as the error tells you to? Or, if your t1 is smaller, try inverting them? And you say you get this when you switch the tables.... when you DON'T switch them, what do you get?

Comment: when I invert the tables on the join error msg:  Error: 3.74 - 3.167: The JOIN operator's right-side table must be a small table. Switch the tables if the left-side table is smaller, or use JOIN EACH if both tables are larger than the maximum described at http://goo.gl/wXqgHs.   If I try the join each it requires an ON clause..which there is no linking variables among the two tables..

Comment: hmmmm... Not sure about this, but I think you could do "ON t1.IP between..." and have it work... if this doesn't work, lemme know, there might be a way to use subqueries to get what you want

Comment: Select t1.email ,t1.IP , t2.Local_ID

from  [GeoData.bigtable] as t2 on   [Logs.Customer_Internet_Activity_Information]  as t1

 where  t1.IP between t2.startIpNum and t2.endIpNum   and it through an error..Encountered " "ON" "on "" at line 3, column 32. Was expecting: <EOF>

Comment: @ticketcitymr you put an ON on a join clause, I assumed you had the basic SQL-fu to get that, sorry for the assumption. So something like "select [whatever] from t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.IP between t2.startIpNum and t2.endIpNum"

Comment: @Patrice, i tried that and received the error:  Error: 3.69 - 4.41: The JOIN operator's right-side table must be a small table. Switch the tables if the left-side table is smaller, or use JOIN EACH if both tables are larger than the maximum described at http://goo.gl/wXqgHs.  Even though I switched tables...

Comment: and again a JOIN EACH on that doesn't help?

Comment: Select t1.email ,t1.IP , t2.Local_ID

from [Logs.Customer_Internet_Activity_Information] as t1 join each [GeoData.bigtable] as t2  on 

   t1.IP between t2.startIpNum and t2.endIpNum  gave me this error message...Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.
Job ID: practicum-2015:job_SzXAKdTIZyckXWjv8jj6l5zjBuw

Comment: oh, then we might be onto something here. So the query is not too big for the system. Lemme see what I can come up with using sub-queries... I'll try to make a temporary table that contains a boolean for your between you may be able to use afterwards.

Comment: hmmm, looking into it, I don't see an easy solution in the end. I can think of three solutions that could help you, but they are all pretty involved and will take you a while to get around to. YOu can either look into 1)Dataflow or 2) mapreduce to process your data. An other way would be to break your geoData table into IPs, not ranges. So instead of having a "start" and "end", each IP in the range will have its own row. This way you CAN do an = on your ON clause.

Comment: You may also want to look into this article http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2014/03/geoip-geolocation-with-google-bigquery.html

Answer (score 0):

So the immediate problem you are running into is that Google does not allow `cross join each`.

This is a bit of a hack, but if performance is not an issue for you you could try:

```
select
  t1.email
  ,t1.IP
  ,t2.Local_ID

from (select true as dummy, email, Ip from [TablewithcustomerIP address]) as t1
inner join each (select true as dummy,Local_ID, startIpNum, endIpNum from [table with IP ranges]) as t2
  on t2.dummy = t1.dummy

where t1.IP between t2.startIpNum and t2.endIpNum
```

However, the query could take a very long time to finish, if at all. A better solution would be to join on your `where` condition, but that, unfortunately is not possible at the moment. I eagerly await the day Google adds custom join conditions, it is probably the feature from SQL I miss most.

Comment: It timed out...Query Failed
Error: Request timed out. Please try again.
Job ID: practicum-2015:job_UAMbi8hq_RdeBTmED9Ux6_6Akl0

Comment: I was afraid that might happen. Could you give estimates of the size of the two tables and how many ranges in t2 you expect an Ip adress from t1 to fall into?

Comment: @ticketcitymr Another thing that could help, but is highly dependent on the data, would be to use math to create a "subnet" attribute (that would contain the first 2 parts of an IP), and then match THAT with an = on a join. From there, a between in the where clause could work. You'd need to divide your IP by (256*256) to get the first 2 parts of your IP, and then match that with the ranges on an =... but it REALLY depends on what ranges you have in that second table.

Comment: table  with IP range ~2 million, tablewith customerIP address ~ 1million.  the customer Ips span 98% of the IP ranges

Comment: I mean the number of ranges a single IP is likely to fall into, to get an estimate of how large the result set will be. That said, I don't have any more ideas as to what you could do. :-/

Comment: @ticketcitymr I think at this point a mathematical trick like the one I suggested where you divide by 65536 and do an = on that division MIGHT help. You need to find a way to have an = on your join that'll let you filter "further down the line" and without knowing your data, it's impossible to give you a tailored answer